# Firefox combobox search

Tags: firefox, search, selection, firebug

There are sometimes comboboxes on web pages (also known as `<select>` tags) with so many options that it is hard to read them all.

A solution would be a plugin or extension to search big comboboxes. I can do it with Firebug, but in order to select an option I have to add a `selected` attribute manually.

I am looking for an extension for Firefox which facilitates this task. If there are solutions for other browsers, I would like to know about them too.

Comment: If this became a problem for you, then we should congratulate the web developer that came up with such a monstruosity.

Comment: @Camilo, did you try to register on LinkedIn?